# Conectar emulador Android con Visual Studio (Xamarin)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, emulación

No conecta el depurador de Visual para Xamarin con el emulador de Android.
Me salen unos warnings. Me comenta que si quiero continuar con ellos y lo instala bien, pero no puedo depurar la aplicación.

**Este es el warning sospechoso.**

```
> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
> Advertencia       Error inesperado en la tarea "XamlCTask".
> System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o
> ensamblado 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb, Version=0.10.0.0,
> PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' ni una de sus dependencias. El
> parámetro no es correcto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070057
> (E_INVALIDARG)) Nombre de archivo: 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb, Version=0.10.0.0,
> PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' ---> System.ArgumentException: El
> parámetro no es correcto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070057
> (E_INVALIDARG))    en System.AppDomain.nApplyPolicy(AssemblyName an)  
> en System.AppDomain.ApplyPolicy(String assemblyName)    en
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.MatchAssemblyName(AssemblyName
> reference, AssemblyName definition)    en
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.FindAssembly(String
> name, IEnumerable`1 probingPaths)    en
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.VsAssemblyResolver.CoreAssemblyResolveHandler(Object
> sender, ResolveEventArgs args)    en
> System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
> String assemblyFullName)    en
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    en
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName)    en System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
> typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
> reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    en
> System.Type.GetType(String typeName)    en
> Mono.Cecil.Cil.SymbolProvider.GetSymbolType(SymbolKind kind, String
> fullname)    en
> Mono.Cecil.Cil.SymbolProvider.GetReaderProvider(SymbolKind kind)    en
> Mono.Cecil.Cil.DefaultSymbolReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition
> module, String fileName)    en
> Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module,
> ReaderParameters parameters)    en
> Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters
> parameters)    en Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String
> fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)    en
> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName,
> ReaderParameters parameters)    en
> Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
> en Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()    en
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()    en
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> en
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() LDCApp.Android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Econtré el problema, se me había deshabilitado Mono Debugging for Visual Studio

Herramientras > Extensiones y actualizaciones... > Mono Debugging for Visual Studio y volverlo a habilitar.

Tras esto reiniciar Visual Studio

Comment: **Excelente!**
Estaba con el mismo problema y habilitando esa opcion corrio ok!